# running an R "subprocess" (fork) within plumber

Tags: r, multithreading, rest, fork, plumber

I am trying to implement a rest API using plumber.
What I would like to happen is that when the request arrives, R will start a background/secondary process, and the API should return immediately with an "ok" message.
The subprocess has the mechanism to inform its result when it is ready - so the user don't need to worry about it.
So I would like to have something like that:

```
#' @post /my_endpoint
function() {

    start_do_something_in_the_background()
    #return the following immediately, without waiting for the process to finish
    return("started...you will be informed...")
}
```

How can this be achieved?

EDIT:::::

ok. package future seems to do the job well.
e.g.

```
future(start_do_something_in_the_background())
```

instead of just calling the function.

If you have other recommendations or comments will be happy to hear.

Comment: If you use the future package to quickly provide a response and allow a long running task to continue the API doesn't seem to shut down properly. It hangs onto the port it was launched in. I'm assume this is because the API that executed quickly has finished, but the subprocess is trying to connect back to it and plumber holds open the port waiting for it. In that case you will end up with an error message that looks like this if you try to restart the process: createTcpServer: address already in use

Comment: @StevenM.Mortimer that's important. any suggestions to overcome that?